# cakephp + aws getobjecturl

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am working on a project which uses cakephp V2.3 with AWS PHP SDK V2.8. It is hosted on AWS EC2 Ubuntu machine. I am trying to get the image which is hosted on AWS S3 by following code

```
try {
    $resultS3 = $this->Amazon->S3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'mytest.sample',
        'Key' => 'files/user/image/35/1440319731.png',
    ));
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    pr($e); //die;
}
```

and the response is following

```
     Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object      
    (
     [structure:protected] => 
     [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [Body] => Guzzle\Http\EntityBody Object
                (
                    [contentEncoding:protected] => 
                    [rewindFunction:protected] => 
                    [stream:protected] => Resource id #135
                    [size:protected] => 
                    [cache:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [wrapper_type] => PHP
                            [stream_type] => TEMP
                            [mode] => w+b
                            [unread_bytes] => 0
                            [seekable] => 1
                            [uri] => php://temp
                            [is_local] => 1
                            [is_readable] => 1
                            [is_writable] => 1
                        )

                    [customData:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [default] => 1
                        )

                )

            [DeleteMarker] => 
            [AcceptRanges] => bytes
            [Expiration] => 
            [Restore] => 
            [LastModified] => Wed, 21 Oct 2015 12:24:59 GMT
            [ContentLength] => 84890
            [ETag] => "7ec848d6e0cd988bf4f3702315a0102b"
            [MissingMeta] => 
            [VersionId] => 
            [CacheControl] => 
            [ContentDisposition] => 
            [ContentEncoding] => 
            [ContentLanguage] => 
            [ContentRange] => 
            [ContentType] => binary/octet-stream
            [Expires] => 
            [WebsiteRedirectLocation] => 
            [ServerSideEncryption] => AES256
            [SSECustomerAlgorithm] => 
            [SSECustomerKeyMD5] => 
            [SSEKMSKeyId] => 
            [StorageClass] => 
            [RequestCharged] => 
            [ReplicationStatus] => 
            [RequestId] => 378C9733A89539A9
        )

)
```

I am able to show the image by following code

```
header("Content-Type: {$resultS3['ContentType']}");
echo $resultS3['Body'];
```

but I want Url so I can display multiple images by fetching from S3.

I tried **[getObjectUrl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl)** too

```
$result = $this->Amazon->S3->getObjectUrl('bucket name','files/user/image/35/1440319731.png');
```

it provide me Url of image but due to `server side encryption (AES256)` (which I am using in `putObject`) I am not able to show that.

I tried to pass encryption type in argument but no success.

`$result = $this->Amazon->S3->getObjectUrl('bucket name','files/user/image/35/1440319731.png', $expires = null, $args = array('ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256'));`

is there any way to fetch object by Url when server side encryption is there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public function read($location){
    return $this->s3->get_object_url($this->bucket, $location, strtotime('+1 minute'), array('https' => true));
}
```